# What is needed to use Ubuntu as a TV

Tags: video, mythtv

I wish to occasionally use my ubuntu computer as a television.  I am in the US and would like to watch over the air (HD)TV shows.  The ideal situation would be the TV show in one window with some mouse & keyboard controls for volume & channel.  I do not want or need a "from the couch" remote driven interface.

What hardware will I need to buy?
What software packages should I install?

Comment: Are we talking about using online sites such as Hulu? Or like recording and watching cable TV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) which has MythTV integrated into Ubuntu. As for hardware have a look at the [Requirements list](http://www.mythbuntu.org/requirements). I hope this assists in your adventures for a TV Computer machine.

Comment: I've been using mythbuntu for about 5 years in the UK and am very happy with it.  It makes an excellent media centre for both recording and watching live.  You can download mythtv from the standard repositories but I'd recommend the mythbuntu repos since they are more regularly updated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a tuner card such as [this one](http://www.pchdtv.com/) to use Ubuntu as a cable TV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use your system as IP-TV. You may want to look at http://www.boxee.tv/

Comment: It seems that the Boxee project is now closed. The team says that in a very subtle way by announcing that they have joined Samsung.